# Fill tool isn't working even with gap closure

Tags: 2d, tools

I'm having issues with blender's fill tool. I can't seem to get it to work properly to fill the character's mouth.

[image]

How do I get the fill tool to work properly in the gif? The loop of the character's mouth is closed, so it's not a unclosed loop issue. I've tried changing the precision settings and the dilate/contract settings, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.